# Clear local storage when user closes window

Tags: javascript, local-storage, dom-events

How do I clear local storage when my website is closed in all the tabs in a browser? means If my user is open my website in multiple tabs, and when user is close browser or close tabs one by one, I need to clear local storage on last tab close event (e.g. on `beforeunload` event).

Does anybody have idea to do this?

Answer (score 5):

This is how you do it:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

Comment: that I already doing. but it should happen only when browser is going to close or last tab of my app is going to close.